# Reading text from one file, to check other text file for matches

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text, system.io.file

So I'm new to VB.NET, and I'm trying to read through 2 separate text files.  File2 first & pulling a variable from it.  I then want to take that variable, and check File1 to see if the string matches.  Both files are relatively large, and I have to trim part of the string from the beginning, hence the multiple splits.  So currently, this is what I have.  But where I'm getting hung up is, how do I get it to check every line to see if it matches with the other file?

```
Public Function FileWriteTest()
Dim file1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(path)
Dim file2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(path)
Do Until file2.EndOfStream
     Dim line = file2.ReadLine()
     Dim noWhiteSpace As New String(line.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray())
     Dim split1 = Split(noWhiteSpace, "=")
     Dim splitStr = split1(0)
     If splitStr.Contains(HowImSplittingText) Then
     Dim parameter = Split(splitStr, "Module")
     Dim finalParameter = parameter(1)
     End If

'Here is where I'm not sure how to continue. I have trimmed the variable to where I would like to check with the other file.
'But i'm not sure how to continue from here.
```

Comment: Think what your missing is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-5.0.  Allows you to read the entire files into memory

Comment: @Hursey 
Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of cleanup notes:

1. Get the lines of your first file by using IO.File.ReadAllLines ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines))
2. Get the text of the second file by using IO.File.ReadAllText ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext))
3. Use String.Replace ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext)) instead of Char.IsWhitespace, this is quicker and much more obvious as to what is going on
4. Use String.Split ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace)) instead of Split (because this is 2021 not 1994).

In terms of what you would do next, you would call String.IndexOf ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof)) on the second file's text, passing your variable value, to see if it returns a value greater than -1. If it does, then you know where at in the file the value exists.

Here is an example:

```vb
Dim file1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("path to file 1")
Dim file2 As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("path to file 2")
For Each line In file1
    Dim noWhiteSpace As String = line.Replace(" ", String.Empty)
    Dim split1() As String = noWhiteSpace.Split("=")
    If (splitStr.Length > 0) Then
        Dim splitStr As String = split1(0)
        If splitStr.Contains(HowImSplittingText) Then
            Dim parameter() As String = splitStr.Split("Module")
            If (parameter.Length > 0) Then
                Dim finalParameter As String = parameter(0)
                Dim index As Integer = file2.IndexOf(finalParameter)
                If (index > -1) Then
                    ' finalParameter is in file2
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. Makes a lot of sense, and seems like it would save on execution overhead as well.
& LOL at the not 1994 comment, I told you I was new to VB xD

Comment: @PJHytfihS Yeah, I like to poke fun because the BASIC syntax has been around forever. Sometimes, holdovers from older languages get used a lot in online examples. I personally try to show .NET style syntax because it makes the transition to other .NET languages (like C#) easier.